# Nginx reroute depending on request

Tags: nginx, routes

So I am trying to configure nginx so that file could get and process diffrent requests.
For example, two kinds of urls: `www.example.com/trips/some-slug/`, and the other one would be `www.example.com/trips/?var=some-value`. I have routing rule for a file:

```
location ~ ^/trips/(.*)/?$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /views/trips.php?slug=$1;
}
```

This sends a GET request. Which I can pick up, but I cannot pick up the second variant of example url, which just gets ignored by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle both types of URI in a named location:

```
location /trips/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @trips;
}
location @trips {
    rewrite ^/trips/$ /views/trips.php last;
    rewrite ^/trips/([^/]*)/?$ /views/trips.php?slug=$1 last;
}
```

Note that the example uses a *prefix location*, which has a different precedence order. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details. You can, of course, continue to use a *regular expression location*.